# Should UAC be turned on or off on servers?

Tags: server, windows-server, uac

So there a number of sources (e.g. [this](http://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/Why-User-Account-Control-in-Windows-is-necessary)) that recommend leaving UAC (User Account Control) turned on on PCs, however there isn't much talk about UAC on servers.

In fact the only thing I could find was [this](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=48712) old discussion from 2009.

I guess some would say that programs running in the background of servers would be obstructed by this (as such pop-ups wouldn't be seen by a computer user). But wouldn't they have to be allowed even before they directly attempt to make relevant changes?

How useful would it be to turn UAC on on servers?

Answer (score 3):

Whatever reasons UAC should be kept enabled, it aims (at least theoretically) to mitigate the impact of a potentially malicious program. According to Microsoft:

> Under certain constrained circumstances, disabling User Account
>   Control (UAC) on Windows Server can be an acceptable and recommended
>   practice.These circumstances occur only when all the following
>   conditions are true:
>
> 1. Only administrators are allowed to log on to the Windows-based server interactively at the console or by using Remote Desktop
>      Services.
> 2. Administrators log on to the Windows-based server only to perform legitimate system administrative functions on the server.
>
> If either of these conditions is not true, UAC should remain enabled.
>   For example, if the server enables the Remote Desktop Services role so
>   that nonadministrative users can log on to the server to run
>   applications, UAC should remain enabled. Similarly, UAC should remain
>   enabled if administrators run risky applications on the server such as
>   web browsers, email clients, or instant messaging clients, or if
>   administrators perform other operations that should be performed from
>   a client operating system such as Windows 7.

([Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2526083/disabling-user-account-control-uac-on-windows-server))